# I asked a question that would be unhelpful to its field, even misleading, but the answers and comments may be helpful, should I delete it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, bad-questions

I recently asked a question that was rather ignorant, and I had more problems in my code than I addressed, as I didn't know what on earth I was doing.

BUT! The answers and comments to said question are rather helpful, and point out my many errors, and I think they may be rather beneficial to some beginners.

Should I:

- delete the question because it is so horrible?
- do nothing?
- or should I do something different?

Something to note is that I don't have enough knowledge to fix the holes I didn't previously know I had, so I can't edit the question into something reasonable.

Post: [Lex and Yacc to make compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123706/lex-and-yacc-to-make-compiler)

Comment: You cannot delete the contributions made by other SO users.  Just come back later when you have a better answer, there is no hurry.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time a 'horrible' question led to some useful answers. I see it all the time. Don't worry about it - it may well be useful to others.